# my text is not adjusting with screen size

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I want that the text "LETS SAVE PETS" and "We need you in this mission" to be responsive according to the screen size but what happening is they doesn't shrink when the screen size is small and ends up adding a lot of white and empty space to the website. I have used  also but it is not working according to my will. Guys please help me. My website is http://letsavepet.com/ . Image I used here for background is different from the website one. Forget that and please help me.
HTML and CSS code is as below

```css
/*This is for links*/
a{text-decoration: none;
color: Black;}

div#sub{display: inline;
color: #339900;}

body {margin:0;}

/*This is for navigation*/
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.topnav a {

  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

 /*This is the end*/

/*This is for parallax scrolling*/
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('http://letsavepet.com/images/20170122_150254.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
/*This is the end*/


/*This is for header*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;}

.top-container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;}

.content {
  padding-top: 14px;}

.header {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: #4caf50;
  z-index:100;}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 64px;}
/*This is the end*/

/*This is for text*/
 .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 120px;}

.sub-text{ position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: apple chancery;}

 /*This is for footer*/
 .footer {
    background-color: #0b0c0c;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 40px;}

 .footer_2{background-color: #1e1f21;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 color: white; }

 div#info{ color: #9fa1a3;}


 .copy_reg{float:right;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 10px; }

 /*This is for media buttons*/
 .fa {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;}

 .media{font-size: 20px;
   padding-right: 60px;
   float: right;
   display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Lets Save Pets</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body style=background:white>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="news.html">News</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="joinus.html">Join Us</a>
  <a href="aboutus.html">About</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="text"><b>LETS&nbsp;SAVE&nbsp;PETS</b></div>
<div class="sub-text"><b>We need you in this mission!</b></div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div class="content" style="background-color:white;">

<h1><u>Saving a life is easier than you think.</u></h1>
<p><font size="5">
“You can do it!” Every day, we say those four magical words to people around the globe who
want to help animals in need but are unsure of their abilities. With some friendly encouragement
and guidance, you’ll be amazed at what you can accomplish.

<h2>Helping to save animals</h2>

Each of us can help bring about a time when there are No More Homeless Pets. In fact, that’s just
what it is going to take — every person reading this article committing to do just a little bit to
reach this goal. Sure, many of us think we can’t make a difference for one reason or another, but
the truth is that no matter how little time, money or experience you have, you can still save
an animal’s life. It’s easier than you think, and makes you feel good, too.
<br /> <br />
We’ve heard from so many of you who want to help but aren’t sure how, so we’re going to tell you
about simple ways that you can make a huge impact. It’s time to do all we can to save the lives of
homeless animals. They’re counting on us — and we know <b>you can do it!
</b></font></p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<div class="media">FIND&nbsp;US&nbsp;ON<a href="https://www.facebook.com/letsavepet/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></div>
CONTACT&nbsp;INFO<br /><br />
<div id="info"><i class="material-icons">local_phone</i> +91 7982189411<br /><br />
<i class="material-icons">local_post_office</i> letsavepet@gmail.com<br /><br />
<i class="material-icons">map</i> 1/5300-C, Street no.- 11,<br />
Balbir Nagar Ext., Shahdara,<br />
Delhi-110032, India</div>
</div>

<div class="footer_2">&nbsp;&nbsp; &copy; Letsavepet
<div class="copy_reg">All Rights Reserved&reg;</div></div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't specify font sizes in px if you want them to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need browser support below IE 11, I would probably use `vw` for the font size. Give the `.text` div `font-size: 11vw;` and `.sub-text: 4vw;` or adjust it as needed. The space between the two divs will probably need to be adjust at different screen widths but the font size will adjust.

```css
/*This is for links*/
a{text-decoration: none;
color: Black;}

div#sub{display: inline;
color: #339900;}

body {margin:0;}

/*This is for navigation*/
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

.topnav a {

  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

 /*This is the end*/

/*This is for parallax scrolling*/
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url('http://letsavepet.com/images/20170122_150254.jpg');

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .parallax {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
/*This is the end*/


/*This is for header*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;}

.top-container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;}

.content {
  padding-top: 14px;}

.header {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background: #4caf50;
  color: #4caf50;
  z-index:100;}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 64px;}
/*This is the end*/

/*This is for text*/
 .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 11vw;}

.sub-text{ position: absolute;
    top: 63%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: apple chancery;}

 /*This is for footer*/
 .footer {
    background-color: #0b0c0c;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 40px;}

 .footer_2{background-color: #1e1f21;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 color: white; }

 div#info{ color: #9fa1a3;}


 .copy_reg{float:right;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 10px; }

 /*This is for media buttons*/
 .fa {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;}

 .media{font-size: 20px;
   padding-right: 60px;
   float: right;
   display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Lets Save Pets</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body style=background:white>

<div class="header" id="myHeader">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="news.html">News</a>
  <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
  <a href="joinus.html">Join Us</a>
  <a href="aboutus.html">About</a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="text"><b>LETS&nbsp;SAVE&nbsp;PETS</b></div>
<div class="sub-text"><b>We need you in this mission!</b></div>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div class="content" style="background-color:white;">

<h1><u>Saving a life is easier than you think.</u></h1>
<p><font size="5">
“You can do it!” Every day, we say those four magical words to people around the globe who
want to help animals in need but are unsure of their abilities. With some friendly encouragement
and guidance, you’ll be amazed at what you can accomplish.

<h2>Helping to save animals</h2>

Each of us can help bring about a time when there are No More Homeless Pets. In fact, that’s just
what it is going to take — every person reading this article committing to do just a little bit to
reach this goal. Sure, many of us think we can’t make a difference for one reason or another, but
the truth is that no matter how little time, money or experience you have, you can still save
an animal’s life. It’s easier than you think, and makes you feel good, too.
<br /> <br />
We’ve heard from so many of you who want to help but aren’t sure how, so we’re going to tell you
about simple ways that you can make a huge impact. It’s time to do all we can to save the lives of
homeless animals. They’re counting on us — and we know <b>you can do it!
</b></font></p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
<div class="media">FIND&nbsp;US&nbsp;ON<a href="https://www.facebook.com/letsavepet/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></div>
CONTACT&nbsp;INFO<br /><br />
<div id="info"><i class="material-icons">local_phone</i> +91 7982189411<br /><br />
<i class="material-icons">local_post_office</i> letsavepet@gmail.com<br /><br />
<i class="material-icons">map</i> 1/5300-C, Street no.- 11,<br />
Balbir Nagar Ext., Shahdara,<br />
Delhi-110032, India</div>
</div>

<div class="footer_2">&nbsp;&nbsp; &copy; Letsavepet
<div class="copy_reg">All Rights Reserved&reg;</div></div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @pavger for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have text resize according to screen size you need to add additional style rule for that size in a media-query. Media queries make it so the css inside of them will only be applied in certain conditions specified inside the "()" brackets. Example:

```
h1 {
 font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {

  h1 {
   font-size: 12px;
  }

}
```

The above h1 will normally be 16px big, and 12px size will only kick in on devices that have smaller screen than 600px (phones).

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries